# Where in 'Lizardo Dungeon' are the Four 'Lian Clamps'?

Tags: seed-rise-of-darkness

A woman in the town of *Leedo* gave me a quest involving searching through the *Lizardo Dungeon* and finding 4 of an item called *Lian Clamp*.

[image: The quest to find the Lian Clamps]

---

I've found three of the four, and though I've scoured the rest (I think) of the dungeon, I haven't been able to find the fourth.

[image: The first two items, in the top right of the second dungeon floor]
These are the first two items, located in the top-right of the dungeon's second floor.

[image: The third item, in the bottom right of the second dungeon floor]
This is the third item, located in the lower left of the dungeon's second floor.

---

Is there a hidden doorway or something that I'm missing?  Where is the last one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't gotten this far into the game yet, but a quick Google search reveals [this post](http://toucharcade.com/forums/showthread.php?t=38657&page=2):

> The "Lian Clamp" side quest:
>   Its hidden in a "bush"!! You cant see it, but I think I approched the bush from the left... 
>   It could be the one you will see to the left when you enter the 2nd floor

Does this help?

**Edit:**

The Fourth *Lian Clamp* is indeed hiding behind a bush, in the **bottom-right** area of the Dungeon's second floor.  In the screenshot below, the chest containing the item is directly to the right of the player's character.

[image: THe last clamp is hidden behind a shrub]

Comment: I actually find the last *clamp* quite by accident **just** before reading this answer.  I'll edit some info into it, and award you the bounty.  Thanks!

Comment: @GnomeSlice Thanks for the edit / accept. Sorry I couldn't provide you with specific details of the last clamp since my Lv 23 gunner is getting eaten **alive** by ranged mobs.

Comment: Make good use of the *Gun* skill that inflicts status abnormalities on enemies.  It can be handy for slowing them down.  As you gain a higher *Gun* proficiency, you'll also be able to start squeezing off more than one shot at a time before having to 'reload'.